# rule of thumb to group/split your own functions/classes into modules

Tags: python, class, module

**Context**

I write my own library for data analysis purpose. It includes classes to import data from the server, procedures to clean, analyze and display results. It also includes functions to compare results.

**Concerns**

I put all these in a single module and import it when I do a new project.
I put any newly-developed classes/functions in the same file.
I have concerns that my module becomes longer and harder to browse and explain.

**Questions**

I started Python six months ago and want to know common practices:

How do you group your function/classes and put them into separated files?
By Purpose? By project? By class/function?

Or you are not doing it at all?

In general how many lines of code in a single module?

What's the way to track the dependency among your own libraries?

Feel free to suggest any thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the best way to answer this question is to look at what the leaders in this field are doing.  There is a very healthy eco-system of modules available on pypi whose authors have wrestled with this question.  Take a look at some of the modules you use frequently and thus are already installed on your system.  Or better yet, many of those modules have their development versions hosted on GitHub (The pypi page usually has a pointer).  Go there and look around.